# How to put the right answer in the suggested answers? (simple equations quiz)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple equations quiz (with javascript) with 4 suggested answers that I generate randomly. The next equation showing after clicking the right answer on a previous equation is also generated randomly. So my question is: how to make one of the suggested answers to be the right one? When I generate the next equation, I keep the answer in a variable. I tried to put it in the array with suggested answers with splice(), but it does not work. Below are some of my lines of code. Every help is welcome! Thanks!

```
function generateRandomAnswers(next){
    var index=0;
    var array=[
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML=generateOneNumber(), //first answer
        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML=generateOneNumber(), //second 
        document.getElementById("third").innerHTML=generateTwoNumbers(), //third
        document.getElementById("fourth").innerHTML=generateTwoNumbers() //fourth
    ];

    random=array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    console.log("Random answer: "+random); //one random answer from the suggested

    if(random!=next){ //next is the answer to the newly generated equation
        random=next;
    }

    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]==random){
            index=i; //index of random
            break;
        }
    }

    array.splice(index, 0, next);
    console.log("The array after splice(): "+array);
}
```